# CSRF token missing or incorrect in signup

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to add a signup function to my website, this is what I have done so far...

- added {% csrf_token %} in home.html
- use render instead of rendor_to_response
- added the middleware 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'

home.html:

```
<div class="panel right">
    <p>
        <form action="/signup" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in user_form %}
            {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
        </form>
    </p>
</div>
```

Signup method in views.py

```
def signup(request):
    user_form = UserCreateForm(data=request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if user_form.is_valid():
            username = user_form.clean_username()
            password = user_form.clean_password2()
            user_form.save()
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return render(request,'blog.html')
        else:
            return render(request,'index.html')
    return redirect('/')
```

What's wrong with my code?